# ReportViewer - Export report programmatically to a specific location without showing save dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I currently have a Windows Forms `ReportViewer` that fetches information from an `SSRS` report.

When the information is fetched I have the option to export them to a PDF, Word or Excel document, to do this, **first**, I need to *save* to see the document.

I would rather have it the other way, which is, export the results to a specific file and then, save the document if that's my choice.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle `ReportExport` event of `ReportViewer` and set `e.Cancel=true;` then using `Render` method of its `LocalReport` or `ServerReport` property, export it to desired location.

Use `LocalReport` for rdlc reports and `ServerReport` for rdl reports. In below code I decided to use the property using value of `ProcessingMode`.

This way, when the user clicks on one of available options in `Export` button, the report will be exported to the specified format at the location which you set in code:

```
private void reportViewer1_ReportExport(object sender, 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportExportEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;
    string[] streams;
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;

    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Report report;
    if (reportViewer1.ProcessingMode == Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local)
        report = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
    else
        report = reportViewer1.ServerReport;

    var bytes = report.Render(e.Extension.Name, e.DeviceInfo,
                    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.PageCountMode.Actual, out mimeType,
                    out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

    var path = string.Format(@"d:\file.{0}", fileNameExtension);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);


    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exported to {0}", path));
}
```

**Note:** Also don't forget to attach `reportViewer1_ReportExport` to `ReportExport` using designer or code, if you forget you will see the dialog.

Comment: By some reason, it still shows the save dialog. I'm using Remote processing mode, does that matter?

Comment: Yes probably it does matter. But at the moment I don't have access to a Report Server to test a solution for Remote processing mode. BUt for local processing mode, I've tested it and it works properly.

Comment: I checked it using report server too. The only change which you need was using `reportViewer1.ServerReport` instead of `reportViewer1.ServerReport`. I made the change in code. Also don't forget to attach `reportViewer1_ReportExport` to `ReportExport` using designer or code, if you forget you will see the dialog.

Comment: Will that code work if I have no SSRS server and my reports are running using ReportViewer?

Comment: @Mark, Yes it works.

Comment: OK, good to know. In your code you are showing how to save newly generated file with a specific name. But will save the report on the server, what if I want to download bytes as a stream with a specific name? IS a way of doing it without saving the files on the server?

Comment: @Mark the example is running in the client app; to improve the code, instead of using a constant file path, just show a SaveFileDialog and let the user choose the file name and save it to that file.

Comment: For cases that you want to export a report from SSRS (server mode) then you can use the reporting service API. Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441235/3110834

Comment: You may also find this post useful (print report without showing preview): https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441235/3110834

Comment: I think the solution you are pointing at requires SSRS Server. I dont have one. The report is processed in the backend using ReportViewer.

Comment: Is it a web app or a windows app? If it's a windows app, then just show the modal and choose the folder and save it. If it's a web app, use the solution to generate the file, then write the file to the output stream (response).